# Control speed of apache (localhost)

Tags: apache, xampp, wamp, wampserver

Occasionally in some of my PHP projects, I feel the need to decrease the speed of the connection, to look like a common internet. I use wampserver 2.2, and would like to know if there is a possibility of slowing the apache for at least a 800kb / s?

If this is not possible through the wamp, xampp can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a debug proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Here is a link with information on how to do this [limiting-your-internet-connection-speed](http://donchevp.blogspot.com.es/2009/11/limiting-your-internet-connection-speed.html).